# IoC using Autofac: How to new up during runtime?

Tags: c#, runtime, inversion-of-control, autofac

To achieve IoC I used to set up instances using DI as following:

```
class Foo
{
    IBar _bar
    
    public foo(IBar bar)
    {
        _bar = bar;
    }   
}
```

Anything that is newed up is then done by autofac. But how do I (or can I) use autofac to achieve independency when assigning new instances isn't possible at startup?

E.g.

```
class Foo
{
    List<IBar> _barList;
    
    public foo(List<IBar> barList)
    {
        _barList = barList;
    }   
    
    FooFunction()
    {
        _barList.Add(new Bar(new qux));
    }
}

public class Baz : IBaz
{
    Iqux _qux;
    
    Baz(Iqux qux)
    {
        _qux = qux;
    }
}
```

Here I added "qux" as well to show what I likely want to achieve. No problem if everything is set up at startup. But because I don't now the numbers of "buz" items the list is going to have at startup I have to add "buz" items during runtime (that requires "qux").

Well, the very goal is to get testable modules. Therefore I don't want to mention the class but only its interface, which is not possible if I have to new up something (or am I wrong?).

Comment: Are you looking for [delegate factories](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html)? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Well I guess pretty much what I was looking for. I'll have to try it out and understand it.

Comment: If it's not exactly what you want, you could also DIY delegate factories and manually register them with the container.